# SQL Server Bulk Insert Failure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, bulkinsert

Consider the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[inputdata](
    [Name] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [AddressStreet] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [AddressStreet2] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [Zip] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Phone] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Campus] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Access] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Degree] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Unknown1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Unknown2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IdentType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Unknown3] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

And the insert script:

```sql
SET ANSI_DEFAULTS ON

BULK INSERT dbo.inputdata
FROM 'C:\inputdata.csv'
WITH (
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
   ,ROWTERMINATOR='\n' 
)
```

Why is the following error output:

> The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 15. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.

DataRow 1 (I manually added the \n for this question, the character exists in each row from the file):

```
1CRESCENT CITY BARTENDING INSTITUTE,209 N. BROAD AVE., ,NEW ORLEANS,LA,70119,.,Regular,Private,1-2 years,Diploma, , ,IPEDSUNIT,158617,\n
```

Comment: You'll need to also show the structure of your `inputdata` table!

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra field terminator at the end of the line.  An extra field terminator can cause it to throw general errors.

I hope this helps!

One way to ensure files get loaded that have strange items like an extra field terminator or text qualified fields using a bulk insert is using a format file.  The link below explains how to create one of those files.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I tried loading the sample row with the extra terminator. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your problem and everything worked.
Until I tried converting the file into UNIX format, where the linefeed is different. This got me the following message:

```
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 15 (Unknown3).
```

Try to look at your file with a hex editor.